JDK cannot be found
I wanted to add Unity Ads (Advertisement Legacy) to my project. It still builds fine and everything, but like every 5 mins I get error that I need to install OpenJDK. It is really annoying. This did not happen before I installed Advertising package. Also, sometimes android resolver pops up but does nothing. I also had issues before with something called android gradle (I was not able to do notifications). I tried deleting and reinstalling JDK and SDK and so from unity hub, but it deos not detect that I deleted them (I have restored them from bin now).
When I launch build on adroid phone, ad click a button to load the ad, nothing happens, even though ads being initialized.
The warning I keep getting:

Preferences > External Tools:


It looks like you're using Unity 2022.3.17f1, which is 9 months out of date. Try upgrading to the latest version of Unity 2022 in case the issue has been fixed.

Can I do a backup to the old editor and project and go back if new editor does not work or something like that occurs? I have never done such an update before so it is likely that something will go wrong...

are you sure that you are using correct JDK which comes with unity? try to open cmd and enter "java -version" to check version and make sure the version matches with expected version of unity.

From another forum someone told me to do echo %JAVA_HOME%, wich just printed out %JAVA_HOME%... Java -version changes the title of the window for a second or so to the name but with " Java" at the end, and after that it prints out an empty line. I did not install any third party JDK, just the one thats installed via Unity Hub (Install Modules > Android Build Support > Java Development Kit)

You should not have any problems upgrading to a newer minor version, e.g. you should be able to upgrade from 2022.3.x to any newer version of 2022.3 (such as 2022.3.44f1) without issues. As for downgrading, sometimes you can downgrade minor versions without any issues, and sometimes you have to return to a backup. If you are following best practices, you should be using a version control system (VCS) such as Git, which inherently backs up your project. If you are not using a VCS, put your game on hold and learn how to use a VCS.
